# Apache CookieTracking, what's the spec for the access log entry of the cookie?

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies

Let's say my apache config contains the following

```
CookieTracking on
CookieName userfault
CookieDomain userfault.com

LogFormat "%{userfault}C" userfaultlog
CustomLog /var/log/userfault.com/access.log userfaultlog
```

I see that the log then contains lines with `IP.somenumber`, e.g.

```
257.15.13.478.1200074655803685
619.203.17.113.1200174880115935
```

I'd like to know the specifications for this number, more specifically how it can be stored in the most efficient way. I looked around and could only find the default CookieStyle is 'Netscape', but that didn't get me much further.

Can I safely assume it will fit in a 64bit number? Is it even a number (and decimal at that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document for the Netscape Cookie Spec is here: http://web.archive.org/web/20080205173011/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html . What you're logging is the content of the cookie. For example in my site I have:

```
W.X.Y.Z.1251144662259653
Origin=testing
```

I think the number is a timestamp or expire date.

**UPDATE**

In [the source code of mod_usertrack](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.3.2/modules/metadata/mod_usertrack.c), you can find how the cookie ID is generated. The comments say:

> Make Cookie: Now we have to generate
>   something that is going to be pretty
>   unique.  We can base it on the pid,
>   time, hostip

So the number we see is a unique ID for tracking the cookie.

Comment: I think it's some sort of timestamp too, but I'd like to know the exact format, the link you provided is helpfull, but doesn't touch that either...

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks alot, somehow didn't occur to me to dig in the source code...for anyone else: the number trailing the IP is generated by apr_time_now(), which returns a 64 bit timestamp (microseconds since epoch)